# What is known or conjectured regarding three dimensional random triangulations?

Tags: random-graphs

Uniform measure on random triangulations of the two dimensional sphere and their limits are rather well understood. Are there any results or heuristics regarding three dimensional analogues?

Comment: In what sense are uniform measures on random triangulations of the sphere understood? Do you have good references?

Comment: @Igor Rivin: B Iruth might be referring to the work by Le Gall, Miermont and others on the scaling limit(s) of planar maps, see e.g. http://arxiv.org/abs/1101.4856 for an introductory reference.  The study of these measures is certainly not complete, but there's a reasonable body of work.  On this site, see also http://mathoverflow.net/questions/44759/essentially-one-random-metric-on-mathbbs2